# equivalent regex for my string

Tags: python, regex

I have write regex for the following string to find it inside http response:

```
 ** server can\'t find mywebdomain.com: NXDOMAIN
```

P.S: This is its structure in http response :

```
** server can\'t find mywebdomain.com: NXDOMAIN\n \n
```

Here is my regexes but seems there is something wrong

```
[*].*(\r\n|\r|\n)
[*].*NXDOMAIN
```

Can you tell me what is the problem here?

Comment: There are a couple of flaws with these "regexes" - what do you actually want to achieve/capture? The domain?

Comment: Are you trying to extract data from this string or just see if the regex matches?  What *exactly* are you looking for in the string?

Comment: It the above string hardcoded? Otherwise, I can't quite understand why not just look for `** server can\'t find mywebdomain.com: NXDOMAIN\n \n`.. or the equivalent of whatever you're looking for of course.

Comment: I am looking to extract this sentence from the response: server can\'t find mywebdomain.com: NXDOMAIN

Comment: @user2091416: You might simply do `if '** server can\'t find mywebdomain.com: NXDOMAIN' in whatever_haystack_you_have:`

Comment: @nir0s it is the output of http response and need to have regex to find it from big response

Comment: @Jan due to some limitation I have to write regex for it .. if its impossible that would be fine to extract only NXDOMAIN by regex

Comment: Did you try this one: `\*\*\sserver\scan\\'t\sfind\s.*: NXDOMAIN\s*$`.

Comment: See [`\*\* server can't find (\S+):\s*(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/ZWvux8/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import re

st = r'** server can\'t find mywebdomain.com: NXDOMAIN\n \n'

if re.match(r"[*]{2}\s+server\s+can\\'t\s+find\s+mywebdomain.com:\s+NXDOMAIN",st):

```
print('Match')
```

else:

```
print('Not found')
```

Match